# Unable to execute system commands from PHP

Tags: php, shell, exec

I am trying to execute a couple of scripts by using a remote interface.  The environment is Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi (although I will be using Debian later as well) running LAMP.

The files are test.php and test.sh in the root directory of the webserver (say example.com)
test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo pkill chromium-browse
sudo reboot
```

test.php

```
<?php
$output=null;
$resultCode=null;
exec("./test.sh", $output, $resultCode);
// $ouptut = shell_exec('./test.sh 2>&1');  //tried this too
// echo shell_exec("./test.sh");  // as well as this
echo "Returned with status $resultCode and output:\n";
print_r($output);
?>
```

Initially, I had used

```
chmod u+x test.sh
```

but got an error code of 126.  So I did this:

```
chmod 777 test.sh
```

Now I get an error code of 1, but it still doesn't execute. I have also tried

```
 sudo visudo
```

then added

```
pi ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
```

(pi is the current loggedin user)
Currently I am getting this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
    [2] => Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
    [3] => 
    [4] =>     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    [5] =>     #2) Think before you type.
    [6] =>     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
    [7] => 
    [8] => sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
)
```

Note:  I use sudo all the time at the command line without being asked for a password.

I do have another php file in  the same directory that executes an actual system command successfully.  It has this line:

```
$uptime =  exec("uptime");
```

which works just fine, so I know system commands are possible.  Is there any way to do this?  I have seen other similar questions on SO and other sites, but none of those answers have worked for me.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this PHP script at the command line or from a web-server?

Your web server is not likely to by running with the `pi` user. Most web server installations are configured to run as (e.g.) user `www-run`, so any `su` permissions you have assigned to the `pi` user will not apply.

Comment: I have given the pi user the ownership (it's the login account and part of the sudo group) and also assigned the files to the www-data group.

Comment: It's not a matter of who owns the files but who owns the process that's using the files.
Are you running this PHP script at the command line or from a web-server?

Comment: Through Webserver in a browser.  As noted $uptime =  exec("uptime"); works.  So I think it is a permissions issue, since I am trying to pkill the browser and then reboot. At least pkill should work?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password

Comment: Something worked.  I tried multiple suggestions most recently as suggested by @YourCommonSense  Now, I have to recreate it to see which one it was. :-)  Will report back.

Comment: Why don't you try running `$username =  exec("whoami");` so you can see which account on the operating system is used for [php-fpm](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background processes like the web server do not run under the logged in username but have their own user ids.

If you do `ps axu` on your command line, you can determine the user that the web server process is running as. This is just an example from my Ubuntu machine using `apache` but your result will be very similar:

```
www-data 15511 0.0 0.2 371988 39800 ? S 09:24 0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2
```

That `www-data` is the user name of the process that's running apache.
So you need to give `su` privileges to that user to enable it to run `su` commands rather than the `pi` user.

I should warn you that this is a massive security issue, and you're basically giving external web-users permission to hack and destroy anything they like on your system... but if this is a hobby project and you have no external users, then it's not so important.

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty since there is very little time left and your solution probably was correct and I haven't had time to create a new pi to test it.  Thanx!